# Capturing Debezium Old Events

Tags: debezium

Currently i'm working with debezium and I want to capture update messages and old messages in the database before creating Debezium connection but i couldn't make it.

I tried to make snapshot.mode initial but it didn't work i only get the data of current table there is no data about old update and deletions. Is there any way to make it?

Regards

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It depends on the source database type. PostgreSQL for instance does not create change records if there are not CDC clients attached or pglogical not enabled. MS SQLServer only records events until age of 3 days with default configuration, if CDC is enabled. Please provide the source database type. Also I wonder which problem you want to solve with the old change events. In most cases only the last state is of interest.